# Is it possible to have a pc with all components passively cooled (no fans)

Tags: cooling

Not a top performance pc but not a low end pc either. I guess you can get a passively cooled video card and a ssd drive, but what about the cpu and the power supply?

Comment: You ought to check out Thermal Right Ultra Extreme 120 or Noctua.

Comment: You can also get a hybrid active/passive solution by using thermister-controlled fans: the fans' RPM ramps up with the temperature of the case and they can shut off when the case is cool enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Silent PC Review](http://www.silentpcreview.com/) is an excellent resource on this topic.

They reviewed a completely passively cooled PC: [Fanless Ultra Powerhouse PC by EndPCNoise](http://www.silentpcreview.com/article301-page1.html).

Also, they list two fanless PSU's on their [Recommended Power Supplies](http://www.silentpcreview.com/Recommended_PSUs) article and at least one CPU heatsink that works without a fan on their [Recommended Heatsinks](http://www.silentpcreview.com/article30-page1.html) article.

If your objective is a quiet PC, I recommend pairing a large, high quality fan that spins at low RPM with a high quality PSU and heatsink. The air circulation will be barely audible, but add significant cooling to your system.

Comment: +1 for Silent PC Review.  Check out their forums.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I ran a 2.4GHz Core 2 Duo off a solid-state heatsink (albeit a fairly expensive one) and a passive video card, and it was fairly high end (at its time). There should be no problem doing that.

Comment: Can you give me a link to the heatsink i would be interested to see it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it sometime in 2004 or 2005 with a [Thermalright XP-120](http://www.silentpcreview.com/article186-page1.html) for the CPU and a [Aerocool VM-101](http://www.aerocool.us/cooler/vm-101/vm-101-feature.htm) for the video card.  It has to be possible these days, but my newer Antec 900 has very quiet 120mm fans.  A more modern version should still be based on heat pipes (good for cooling satellites too).

I've never seen a passively cooled power supply in a normal tower case, but there are smaller cases now with external AC-DC converters, so I wouldn't be surprised to see a case with a fan-less power supply.

This [size comparison from Gruntville.com](http://www.gruntville.com/reviews/image.php?i=http://www.gruntville.com/images/hardware/heatsinks/XP_120/IMG_0015_T.jpg) shows how much larger the XP-120 is (especially with the fan attached) when compared to a stock fan from the P4 days.

Answer (score 1):

A ULV CPU won't need anything beyond a large heatsink and a modest, fanless PSU. If you're willing to go beyond x86 then there are lots of decent, low-power CPUs, such as the ARM family.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [TNN-500](http://www.zalman.co.kr/ENG/product/Product_Read.asp?idx=116) from a while back.

[image]

Comment: What a monster.